# Trying to test my randomiser in rspec by passing specific numbers to it

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am currently trying to create a test for the below code. I wrote the test first and then wrote the code and realised my test is not doing what I want it to do.

```
class Weather

  def initialize
    @weather = 'sunny'
  end

  def weather_randomiser
    case rand(1..10)
    when 1..8 then @weather = 'sunny'
    when 9..10 then @weather = 'stormy'
    end
  end

  def stormy?
    weather_randomiser
    @weather == 'stormy'
  end
end
```

My test is as follows:

```
require 'weather.rb'

describe Weather do
  it 'randomises weather and sets the weather to the randomised result' do
    weather = Weather.new
    allow(weather).to receive(:weather_randomiser).and_return(9)
    expect(weather).to be_stormy
    allow(weather).to receive(:weather_randomiser).and_return(2)
    expect(weather).to_not be_stormy
  end
end
```

Can you please explain how I go about testing the weather_randomiser and stormy? methods similar to this/ is it possible with my code.

Further could you explain how you got to where you did as I would like to understand not just have an answer.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: I believe you can use [allow_any_instance_of](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/allow-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class) and separate it into two test cases to be clearer

Comment: I tried to use allow_any_instance_of and it still is not appearing to change @weather to stormy as it should

Answer (score 0):

Your `weather_randomiser` does too many things:

1. It generates a random number
2. It maps a random number to a string value
3. It updates an instance variable

To make things more testable, you could split those out, e.g.:

```rb
def weather_randomiser
  rand(1..10)
end

def set_weather(value)
  @weather = case value
    when 1..8 then 'sunny'
    when 9..10 then 'stormy'
  end
end

def stormy?
  set_weather weather_randomiser
  @weather == 'stormy'
end
```

It does introduce an awkward coupling between the randomiser and setter; changing the former requires looking at the latter ... ymmv

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be something like this. Doesn't require use of `any_instance_of`, although stubbing anything on `subject` is also not recommended.

```rb
describe Weather do
  subject(:weather) { described_class.new }

  before(:each) do
    allow(weather).to receive(:rand).with(1..10).and_return(random_value)
  end

  context 'when random value is in 1..8' do
    let(:random_value) { 8 }

    it { is_expected.not_to be_stormy }
  end

  context 'when random value is in 9..10' do
    let(:random_value) { 10 }

    it { is_expected.to be_stormy }
  end
end
```

Another way to write it without exposing private implementation details would be like this:

```
describe Weather do
  subject(:weather) { described_class.new }

  let(:stormy_weathers) do
    (1..10).map do |val|
      allow(weather).to receive(:rand).and_return(val)
      weather.stormy?
    end
  end

  it 'is stormy 20% of the time and sunny 80% of the time' do
    expect(stormy_weathers)
      .to match_array(Array.new(2, true) + Array.new(8, false))
  end
end
```

This version will pass even if you change the internal implementation to use 1..2 and 3..10 as the sunny and stormy ranges respectively. As long as the ratio is still 80/20.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use the following snippet. Here you want to stub the `rand` function itself. I really don't recommend that. I would recommend if you have your class that may be called `Randomizer` and it contains the `random` class. Stubbing classes like `Object` is not good at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative '../weather.rb'

RSpec.describe Weather do
  it 'randomises weather return stormy' do
    allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:rand).and_return(9)
    weather = Weather.new
    expect(weather).to be_stormy
  end

  it 'randomises weather return sunny' do
    allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:rand).and_return(4)
    weather = Weather.new
    expect(weather).to_not be_stormy
  end
end
```

Comment: If you want to mock `weather_randomiser` function. Then you need to change the implementation of `stormy?` method inside `Weather` class to assign the value returned to `@weather` instance rather than calling it on the fly.

Comment: I am pretty new to ruby. Why would you not recommend stubbing the Object class for testing? As surely it does not adjust the class outside of the test so is only modified for the test it is used in? Sorry if it is a stupid question

Comment: Amr Adel, I think I understand what you are saying and I did try that, however, it did not meet the goals of how I wanted the class to act with my other classes.

Comment: @Chris It would make more sense to just stub `rand` on the instance of `Weather`. e.g. `weather = Weather.new; allow(weather).to receive(:rand).and_return(9)`. Even RSpec is not a fan of [`allow_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) and in this case there is a very simple way to avoid it without any side effects.

Comment: Chris, It is not stupid at all bro, It is just once the code comes bigger and imagine you started to call other functions that is also using `rand`. Now stubbing it that way would cause a real hassle to handle. I believe doing what engineersmnky suggested is much better I guess or it is equivalent what I suggested to in the first comment which will make this rand in a separated component and stubbing it will be easier I guess.